# VB.NET: Pass List(Of String) to C++

Tags: vb.net, collections, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

I'm trying to pass a VB.NET List(Of String) collection to a [managed] C++ class [constructor) but am getting an error

Error   BC30657 'New' has a return type that is not supported or parameter types that are not supported.

The receiving C++ class is expecting a List parameter which I thought was the C++ equivalent - but clearly it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?
Any recommendations for reading materials for CLI/Non-CLI considerations/how-tos/gotchas?

VB.NET:

```
    Dim myStrList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    '<snip> populate list        
    Dim myObj As MyManagedClass = New MyManagedClass(myStrList)
    'ERROR: argument not recognized
```

C++/CLI:

```
    public ref class MyManagedClass
    {
        private:
        //stuff
        public:
        MyManagedClass(List<String^> myStringListIn);
    }
```

Comment: I think I may have solved it. Make the list itself managed as well as the strings:
Replace

        `MyManagedClass(List<String^> myStringListIn);`

with

        `MyManagedClass(List<String^>^ myStringListIn);`

Comment: That would have been my first thought, that you need the hat on the `List` as well as on the `String`s it contains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Craig. Are there any books out there that you [or anyone else] would recommend that go into the nitty-gritty of these managed/un-managed/marshaling/casting issues? Rgds Steve

Comment: Not from me, no.  The only books I have are for standard C++.  Everything I know about .NET I've learned from the online documentation, existing code, Stack Overflow various blogs (I'd especially recommend Raymond Chen and Eric Lippert), and the Googles.